# Simple javascript will only work with a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to understand some of the fundamentals of javascript and DOM manipulation, and I've run into major roadblock. I'm trying a simple change of style to hide and show. It will work, but ONLY when I put in a breakpoint and run the code step by step. With no breakpoints in chrome developer tools it won't work. I wrote an equivalent in jQuery to, and ran into the exact same problem. Here is javascript:

```js
(function topping() {
  var x = document.getElementById('pizza').value;
  var y = document.getElementById('pizza');
  y.addEventListener('change', changeToppings);

  function changeToppings() {
    if (x == 'Sicilian') {
      document.getElementById('RegToppings').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('SicToppings').style.display = 'block';
    } else if (x == 'Regular') {
      document.getElementById('SicToppings').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('RegToppings').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
#SicToppings {
  display: none;
}
#RegToppings {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<content>
  <select id="pizza">
    <option id="Regular">Regular</option>
    <option id="Sicilian">Sicilian</option>


  </select>
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="buddybox" />buddy
  <select size="5" id="SicToppings">
    <option>mushrooms</option>
    <option>pepperoni</option>
  </select>
  <select size="5" id="RegToppings">
    <option>olives</option>
    <option>pasta</option>
  </select>
</content>
```

and here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("#pizza").change(function () {
    var x = $("#pizza").value;
    if (x == "Sicilian")
    {
        $("#RegToppings").delay(1000).hide();
        $("#SicToppings").delay(1000).show();
    }
    else if (x == "Regular")
    {
        $("#SicToppings").delay(1000).hide();
        $("#RegToppings").delay(1000).show();
    }
    })
})
```

Thank you so much for any assistance you can offer. I'm not just looking for the solution, I'm trying to figure out why this is even happening, I think it has something to do with timing or call backs and I know that this a major component of javascript I have to understand. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't read your code but it can occur if things are going too fast. Try slowing things down?

Comment: Throw all of that into a jsFiddle for us... we can look at the console and see what's going on.

Comment: in your non-jQuery code, the value of `x` is not being updated on-change. In the jQuery, you need to use `x = $("#pizza").val()`.

Comment: You need to let the rendering threads of the display catch up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

Comment: Remove the css style for that and should work fine.

Comment: Here's the fiddle. Thank you for the value x solution, but I don't get why it was working with breakpoints. Chrome said Closure: x = "Sicilian" did this have something to do with it? Also, is there some tool to check for jQuery syntax errors like in Visual Studio? Thank you.

Comment: JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/darnold24/q044b5re/

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the problem with the pure Javascript version is that you are storing the value of `pizza` in `x` at the start of the page instead of when they change selection. This means it will never change and stay as `Regular`.

Just moving this line to the start of `changeToppings()` seems to fix it:

```js
(function topping() {
  var y = document.getElementById('pizza');
  y.addEventListener('change', changeToppings);

  function changeToppings() {
    var x = document.getElementById('pizza').value;
    if (x == 'Sicilian') {
      document.getElementById('RegToppings').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('SicToppings').style.display = 'block';
    } else if (x == 'Regular') {
      document.getElementById('SicToppings').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('RegToppings').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
#SicToppings {
  display: none;
}
#RegToppings {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<content>
  <select id="pizza">
    <option id="Regular">Regular</option>
    <option id="Sicilian">Sicilian</option>


  </select>
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="buddybox" />buddy
  <select size="5" id="SicToppings">
    <option>mushrooms</option>
    <option>pepperoni</option>
  </select>
  <select size="5" id="RegToppings">
    <option>olives</option>
    <option>pasta</option>
  </select>
</content>
```

Answer (score 0):

See @Rhumborl's answer for the pure javascript.

For jQuery, `$("#pizza").value;` is returning undefined. The proper way to get the value is `$("#pizza").val();` but you'll need to specify the value in your HTML `<option id="Regular" value="Regular">` Otherwise it'll return the text inside the tag (which in this case would work too I suppose)

How you got it to work with a debug point is beyond me though.